# Python list does not append correctly (IndexError: list index out of range)

Tags: python, list, flask, indexing

I tried different approaches for 3 hours now and I just don't get why this does not work.

```
current_stock_dict = db.execute("SELECT * FROM current_stocks WHERE c_user_id=:user_id ", user_id=session["user_id"])

    # make a list for the mainpage
    mainpage_list = [[],[]]

    # save the lengh of the dict
    lengh_dict = len(current_stock_dict)
    price_sum = 0
    share_sum = 0

    # iterate over all rows in the dict
    for i in range(0, (lengh_dict - 1)):

        # lookup the symbol in the current stocks
        c_symbol = current_stock_dict[i]["c_symbol"]
        lookup_symbol = lookup(c_symbol)

        # append the symbol to the list for the mainpage
        mainpage_list[i].append(c_symbol)

        # append the name of the share
        share_name = lookup_symbol["name"]
        mainpage_list[i].append(share_name)

        # append the count of shares for mainpage
        c_count = current_stock_dict[i]["c_count"]
        mainpage_list[i].append(c_count)

        # append the current price
        share_price = lookup_symbol["price"]
        mainpage_list[i].append("$" + str(share_price))

        # append the total price of all shares
        total_price = float(share_price) * int(c_count)
        mainpage_list[i].append("$" + str(total_price))

        # count up the price and shares
        price_sum += total_price
        share_sum += c_count
```

When i run my website via Flask i get an error message saying: 
**IndexError: list index out of range** 
in the line:
 `mainpage_list[i].append(c_symbol)` 
(and i guess if it did not allready fail there i'd get it for the rest of the lines too).

As long as `lengh_dict = len(current_stock_dict)` is 3 or less (So the SQL db has 3 rows or less) the error message does not appear and the code works fine. I do not really understand lists (and multidimensional lists) in python yet so i would be happy if somebody could explain my mistake to me.

Normally i would print out a lot of things and just try out where the mistake is but i just began using flask and i can't print out lists, dicts or anything if the code stops before reaching the bug.

Thanks allready for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the relevant part of your code.

```
mainpage_list = [[],[]]
for i in range(0, (lengh_dict - 1)):
    mainpage_list[i].append(c_symbol)
```

`mainpage_list` is a list that contains two elements, both of which are empty lists. So, accessing `mainpage_list[0]` is the first list inside `mainpage_list`, and `mainpage_list[1]` is the second empty list. Any index above that will result in an `IndexError`.

It is not exactly clear what you are trying to achieve, but you could initialize `mainpage_list` with the correct number of empty lists inside if that is what you need, e.g. for the case where you want as many empty lists as the length of `current_stock_dict`, you could do

```
mainpage_list = [ [] for _ in range(length_dict) ]
```

Comment: That was exactly what i was trying to achieve. I've tried your code ```mainpage_list = [ [] for _ in range(length_dict) ]``` and that solved it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the list `mainpage_list` is a two element list, and you're trying to access the third element of it.

Generally, when processing lists of indeterminate size, I prefer to iterate and append rather than indexing into the list.

This gives you something like:

```
source = ["abc", "def", "ghi"]  # List of data to process
target = []  # The processed data

for row in source:  # For every row of data
    value = []  # Empty list to accumate result in
    value.append(row[2])
    value.append(row[1])
    value.append(row[0])
    target.append(value)

print(target)
```

which will work for any size of source list.

Applying this to your code gives you:

```
# current_stock is a list of dictionaries.
current_stock = db.execute("SELECT * FROM current_stocks WHERE c_user_id=:user_id ", user_id=session["user_id"])

# make a list for the mainpage
mainpage_list = []

price_sum = 0
share_sum = 0

# iterate over all rows in current_stock
for row in current_stock:
    value = []

    # lookup the symbol in the current stocks
    c_symbol = row["c_symbol"]
    lookup_symbol = lookup(c_symbol)

    # append the symbol to the list for the mainpage
    value.append(c_symbol)

    # append the name of the share
    share_name = lookup_symbol["name"]
    value.append(share_name)

    # append the count of shares for mainpage
    c_count = row["c_count"]
    value.append(c_count)

    # deleted code

    # count up the price and shares
    price_sum += total_price
    share_sum += c_count

    mainpage_list.append(value)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought i would create a two dimensional list by using ```mainpage_list = [[],[]]``` not a list of two lists. That explanation was very helpful!

Comment: @MRVN I don't there there are many languages that actually have 2D lists. All the one I can think of do it as lists of lists.

Comment: You might be right about that but i just started programming and i thought lists in python would work like arrays in languages like c for example. Do you know if there is anything like an array in python? I've read that you can use lists for that.

Comment: lists and arrays are very similar. It's the 2D lists / arrays that get complicated.